# How to use deepreload for autoreload in iPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I currently use this to autoreload in python

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

however, I would like to start using deepreload (https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.lib.deepreload.html)

However the below does not work:

```
import builtins
from IPython.lib import deepreload
builtins.reload = deepreload.reload

%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

How can I get deep autoreload in jupyter

Answer (score 4):

Just reverse the order

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

import builtins
from IPython.lib import deepreload
builtins.reload = deepreload.reload
```